# ordering varchar type is different then what i see in excel

Tags: sql-server-2008

I run the following query

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    Data VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('241.110')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('1340.306')

SELECT * FROM #Temp ORDER BY Data asc
```

Result is

> 1340.306
>   241.110

When I sort same data in excel with order as Smallest to Largest, it has

> 241.110
>   1340.306

In SQL Server i need the same ordering as in excel. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have mixed numerics and text in one column you could use this to sort on numeric values for the numerics.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    Data  varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('241.110')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('1340.306')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('b')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('aa')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('241.2')

SELECT *
FROM #Temp
ORDER BY
  case isnumeric(Data) when 0 then Data end asc, 
  case isnumeric(Data) when 1 then cast(Data as numeric(10,3)) end asc
```

Result:

```
Data
----------
241.110
241.2
1340.306
aa
b
```

**Edit 1** A second column to be treated the same way.

```
SELECT *
FROM #Temp
ORDER BY
  case isnumeric(Data) when 0 then Data end asc, 
  case isnumeric(Data) when 1 then cast(Data as numeric(10,3))end asc,
  case isnumeric(Data2) when 0 then Data2 end asc, 
  case isnumeric(Data2) when 1 then cast(Data2 as numeric(10,3))end asc
```

Comment: hmm, this is intereting, I didn't know you can do CASE in order by. Can I have multiple columns in order by when combined with case, so for example if i have Data1, Data2 columns, can i check for both in same manner?

Comment: @palm - Not sure if I understand what you want but you can have more than one column/statement in order by. In my answer there is two statements in order by separated with a comma. The first returns a string or null, the second returns a numeric or null. You can of course add more statements to the order by clause.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance but let's say i have two columns Data1 and Data2 and if I want to do ORDER BY Data1, Data2 by with the CASE check can you show by example. I am trying it but getting syntax errors

Comment: @palm - Added a version where you have a Date2 column that is treated the same way as secondary sort order.

Answer (score 0):

The sort in sql-server is in alphabetical order and '1' comes before '2'.

To get the same sort as excel, I suggest you use a numeric field instead of VARCHAR.